# Qt Creator source files

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to set up QtCreator to treat .d files as C sources?

Comment: Is there are a particular reason why? IIRC .d files are either DTrace scripts of D language source files.

Unless of course you want to use C++ highlighting for D source code, in which case I have no idea about the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file called CppEditor.mimetypes.xml embedded as a resource in the binary executable. This file contains a list of file extensions that are treated as C++ source files.

It can be found in the source tree here:
src/plugins/cppeditor/CppEditor.mimetypes.xml

I don't think you can change the list without recompiling Qt Creator from source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the limitation of Qt Creator? It might be something in the compiler, though.

Comment: Sure. There is no "Treat there extensions as c/c++" option